# Deleted user still ask for password if try to login

Tags: oracle

I've deleted a user with command 'userdel -r user' but if i try to login with this user (ssh user@ip...) stil ask for password. If i write the password do not work and returns me permission denied, but it should not ask me for password as with any other random user that do not exist.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; but if you try and login using an account that never existed; the system will act as if the username was valid; as that tells you less detail compared with *invalid username* which is it appears what you'd prefer (ie. what you describe happening is actually more secure than providing detail that an invalid username login was attempted).

Answer (score 4):

You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details, but if you try and login using an account that never existed, the system will act as if the username was valid. This gives you less detail compared to *invalid username* which appears to be what you'd prefer (ie. *what you describe happening is actually more security aware than providing detail that an invalid username login was attempted*).

Comment: This seems to be upstream's default behavior.

Comment: Yep, it's the same behavior as my *current* Debian *trixie* box....

Comment: Suppose that X was a user that i have deleted and Y a random name that never existed, now if i try ssh X@ip it asks me for password but i try ssh Y@ip it returns me permission denied (publickey)